# eglot C# Find References

Tags: eglot

For eglot, how can we find references for a variable in C#?

There is no eglot-find-references. Are we supposed to use xref-find-references?

Answer (score 0):

According to Eglot's [README](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot#find-references) you should use `xref-find-references`.

> Eglot here relies on Emacs' built-in functionality as well. `xref-find-references` is bound to `M-?`. Additionally, Eglot provides the following similar commands: `eglot-find-declaration`, `eglot-find-implementation`, `eglot-find-typeDefinition`.

Comment: I only get "No references found for: LSP identifier at point", when running xref-find-references. Is there some store I need to update or something?;)

Comment: I think you should report it as a bug via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.